# ssh shell: disown script is not saving results to a file

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh

I'm running a simple script in ssh shell. My script is doing some computations and at the end is saving results to a file. Because I cannot be connected to the shell I'm doing the following:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
Ctrl + Z 
$ bg 
$ disown
```

Then I "exit" and after logging in again sometimes script is still running, but if it's already done there should be an *output file* -- but it isn't there. If I don't leave the shell at all, everything works fine.

The most surprising thing is that I remember using Ctrl+Z, bg, disown commands in the past for the very same thing, and they worked fine.

I'm using `open(file_name, 'w')` in python to create the output file -- but I'm not sure if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also run `disown -h` to prevent the shell from sending the job a SIGHUP signal and killing it when the shell exits.